# the arms of my puppet appear under the leg

Tags: after-effects, animation

I have created my puppet with pins and the hands are going under the legs and under his beard and i need to make him eat grapes.
The pin layer of the hand is over the pin layer of the leg
thanx for your help

Comment: When you say "the pin layer" are you talking about a layer controlling the pin, e.g. with somethign like DuIK? Are the legs arms and beard all part of the same layer, or are they on separate layers?